# Visual Studio + Localhost: How to manage multiple projects and image paths?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-development, .net-framework, iis-7

I am working with VS 2008 + IIS7 and testing my local machine. I have multiple projects fetched via VSS.

The project images are relative to the root "/images/...", but on my local server that ends up being below the project root (wwwroot instead of wwwroot/project).

How do I properly manage image paths?